# Linked Transactions - looking for clues

Tags: corda

I have a specific use case. Alice issues a transaction to Bob. Bob can deal with this in a number of ways (accept, reject, settle). So far so good.

However, in this scenario Bob can also take the original transaction and generate his own transaction based on this to Carol and Dave. Essentially, if Alice claims $10, Bob can say that Carol should pay $2, Dave $3 and Bob will pay the $5.

Dave could then say that Eve should pay $1 of his share.

Much, but not all,  of the data on the original tx is repeated across the subsequent tx. Some information is not to be shared, ie the original value of $10 should not be known to Eve. Carol and Dave do not know what each other is paying.

There are some complications. If Alice decides to cancel the claim, the cancellation verification code needs to check that the TX to Carol and Dave are also cancelled, otherwise Bob would end up with money he is not entitled to when they settle.

Also, commercially, the sums of the TX that Bob generate can exceed the amount Alice is claiming from him.

I know this is complex, but does can anyone offer me a clue bat as to where to start?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at FungibleStates: https://docs.corda.net/api-states.html#fungiblestate
This idea is make a state that is able to split your original state and distribute to multiple parties.